# Image not appearing in dev server when deployed

Tags: asp.net, css

I 'm using this css to insert an image at right corner of the textbox to appear like a dropdown.

```
.txtbox
{
background-image: url('/Images/Dropdown.png');
background-position: right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
}
```

The image appears perfectly with this type of path reference in my local machine. But when I deployed it to the server the image doesn't show up. Is there something I could differently do to make the image appear in my dev server.

My Directory
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp

```
bin
docs
Images
Scripts
Styles
Default.aspx
Login.aspx
Home.aspx

**Styles:**
style.css
site.css

Style.css has this .txtbox

**Images**
Dropdown.png
Logo.png
```

Comment: If the deployment path is not the same as the deveplopement path, relative to domaine. You could try user relative path (relative to CSS location). Et: your develop on http//localdomain/, the css is in http://localdomain/styles/main.css , your deployment path is http://deployeddomain/somefolder/yourapplication/, your image in http://localdomain/images/Dropdown.png , then change the path to ../images/Dropdown.png) Not enough info to be sure this is targetting you problem, but this kind of things happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use relative paths in HTML/CSS. When you begin a path with `/` it becomes relative to the root of the server. Change the image path relative to the CSS file location. It should work.

Comment: I changed like this and still doesn't show up background-image: url(/Images/Dropdown.png);

Comment: Please post your directory structure including relevant CSS, HTML and image directories and files.

Comment: You have posted only the top level directories. Need to know where the files (CSS containing your background and the corresponding image files) are in the directory structure.

Comment: Pls take a look at my updated code. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Sorted out. This worked background-image: url(../Images/Dropdown.png );

Answer (score 0):

Primary issue: if you are developing on a windows machine then your local machine is not case sensitive, but a linux server might be. Make sure that Dropdown.png is capitalised the same in the HTML and as the file name.

Secondary possibilities:Possible reference error. Try changing the href URL to *//Images*... and see if that makes any difference. Also inspect the element in a browser and check where the reference is currently pointing to. Alternately, use the full path, eg

```
http://www/mysite.com/Images/Dropdown.png
```

while it is on the server.

Comment: I changed like this and still doesn't show up background-image: url(/Images/Dropdown.png);